# How to make a C++ compiler ignore buffer overflow

Tags: c++, security, compiler-errors, buffer-overflow

I want to show a live example of a buffer overflow, for example I want to show the vulnerability in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

constexpr auto INPUT_LENGTH = 4;
int bof1(){
    int ret_value = 0;
    char input[INPUT_LENGTH];
    int i = 0;
    do{
        input[i] = getchar();
    } while(input[i++] != '10'); //enter key
    int 
    return ret_value;
}



int main(){
    cout << "0x" << hex << right << bof1() << endl;
}
```

When I enter an input greater than 4 I get an error of a buffer overflow instead of the buffer overflow happening.
Is there a way to get a buffer overflow to happen nowadays?

edit: I managed to make it so the compiler doesn't return an error, but now no matter how long the input is, I still get 0x0 as an output. Why doesn't the overflow happen?

Comment: You have other problems, as [`std::getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) is declared to return an **`int`**. This is rather important when comparing to the `int` value `EOF` (it's not guaranteed that `char(EOF) == EOF`).

Comment: See if your compiler has options to disable bounds checks and stack corruption checks.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the **verbatim** error message you get.

Comment: What compiler (and what version) are you using and how are you calling it ?

Comment: Here is simple demonstration https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bGxoGT3cc

Comment: This code is so simple that the non-array variables easily fit in registers. You can't buffer overflow to CPU registers (ancient CPU's excluded)

Comment: You could run the code on a bare metal, low-end MCU without any MMU or OS. That leaves the programmer mostly alone to their own devices, letting them write all manner of dangerous code.

Comment: There are many Virtual Machines out there that allow for security testing. Not sure what you need in this scenario, but maybe somebody can point one out. That there are still ways to get buffer overflow to happen seem clear from the amount of vulnerabilities that still roll in, see e.g. [this very readable and informative post about the OpenSSL Punycode vulnerability](https://words.filippo.io/dispatches/openssl-punycode/).

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. Look at the generated assembly code. Also tell us 1: your platform. 2: your compiler+version.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please post your **actual** code.

Comment: And `'10'` -> `10` or better `'\n'`